# Como capturar el texto(letras, signos y numeros) entre comillas simples o dobles seguido de cierta palabra con una regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, substring

```py
import re
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator() #Creo el objeto de la clase Translator()

with open("en-sentiment.xml", "r") as read_file:
    with open("translated_file.xml", "w") as write_file:
        #Por cada linea del archivo que lee vamos a escribir el archivo con la funcion write 
        for line in read_file:
            print(repr(line))

            
            n_sense = re.findall(r"(?:'.*?')|(?:\".*?\")", line) #deberia servir tanto para "" como ''
            print(repr(n_sense))
            tr = translator.translate(n_sense, src='en', dest='es')
            n_sense_translate = tr.text

            line_translate = line.replace(n_sense, n_sense_translate)
            print(line_translate)
            

            #write_file.write(line) #Copiaria y escribiria la misma linea
            write_file.write(line_translate) #Escribe la linea traducida
```

Las lineas del en-sentiment.xml estan estructuradas de este modo:

```
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-00675928" pos="JJ" sense="occurring by turns" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-00676093" pos="JJ" sense="every second one of a series" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-01663359" pos="JJ" sense="of leaves and branches etc" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-01853934" pos="JJ" sense="serving or used in place of another" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="amateur" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-502167" wordnet_id="a-01870636" pos="JJ" sense="lacking professional skill or expertise" polarity="-0.5" subjectivity="0.5" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="amateur" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-525291" wordnet_id="a-01869634" pos="JJ" sense="engaged in as a pastime" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="amateurish" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-502167" wordnet_id="a-01870636" pos="JJ" sense="lacking professional skill or expertise" polarity="-0.4" subjectivity="0.8" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.8" />
<word form="amatory" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-526107" wordnet_id="a-01465214" pos="JJ" sense="expressive of or exciting sexual love or romance" polarity="0.1" subjectivity="0.1" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.8" />
<word form="amazing" wordnet_id="a-01282510" pos="JJ" sense="inspiring awe or admiration or wonder" polarity="0.8" subjectivity="1.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="amazing" wordnet_id="a-02359789" pos="JJ" sense="surprising greatly" polarity="0.4" subjectivity="0.8" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="ambitious" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-502179" wordnet_id="a-00104051" pos="JJ" sense="having a strong desire for success or achievement" polarity="0.5" subjectivity="0.5" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="ambitious" wordnet_id="a-00745642" pos="JJ" sense="requiring full use of your abilities or resources" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="1.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
<word form="amenable" cornetto_synset_id="n_a-503633" wordnet_id="a-00696828" pos="JJ" sense="disposed or willing to comply" polarity="0.2" subjectivity="0.6" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.8" />
```

Siendo que cada linea consta de estos elementos, y yo debo leer linea a linea el archivo .xml pero reemplazar lo que le sigue a `sense=` por su version traducida al español, por ejemplo:

```
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-00675928" pos="JJ" sense="occurring by turns" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
```

Deberia escribirse como:

```
<word form="alternate" wordnet_id="a-00675928" pos="JJ" sense="ocurriendo por turnos" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="0.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />
```

Osea solo debe traducirse lo que esta seguido de `sense=` y dentro de las comillas dobles `""`, pero sin incluirlas.

El problema de esta regex es que detecta todos y no el que empieza con `sense=`, y tambien deja dentro del texto a traducir las comillas dobles, cosa que no deberia hacer. Ademas creo que deberia cambiar el `findall()` por `match()`

Comment: ¿No te sería de utilidad usar un analizador (parser) de XML? En mi opinión sería más práctico de esa forma que leer el archivo y usar regex con todo lo que ello implica. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras En verdad nunca he usado ese analizador que comentas, pero he intentado con regex y se puede, aunque en este caso estoy teniendo problemas para armar ese patron que extraiga especificamente lo que necesito traducir de ese .xml .

Solo por curiosidad(fuera de la pregunta) seria mas rapido si leyese el archivo de ese modo, o no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una búsqueda usando las afirmaciones de regex (regex lookbehind), utiles para encontrar caracteres que están antes o después de tu regex principal y no incluirlos.

Este serie el regex:

`(?<=sense=["\']).*?(?=["\'])`

Se lee así

- Encuentra delante de la tu regex principal (`.*`), la palabra `sense=` más comillas simples o dobles, pero no la incluyas `(?<=sense=["\'])`.
- Seguido de cualquier tipo de caracter `.*`, pero solo coincide con la menor cantidad de caracteres posible `?`
- Seguido de comillas simples o dobles, pero no las incluyas `(?=["\'])`.

## Ejemplo

```py
import re
string= '<word form="ambitious" wordnet_id="a-00745642" pos="JJ" sense="requiring full use of your abilities or resources" polarity="0.0" subjectivity="1.0" intensity="1.0" confidence="0.9" />'
match= re.search('(?<=sense=["\']).*?(?=["\'])',string)

n_sense= match.group()
```

Resultado:

```
requiring full use of your abilities or resources
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la ayuda